# How do insert records in a table that will require no values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do insert records in a table that will require no values

```
Create Table Orders
(
    OrderId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PlacetAt time Default convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 108),
    Placeton date Default GETDATE(),
    Total money Default 0,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `default values`:

```
insert into Orders default values;
```

Or, if you prefer, choose any column other than the identity and insert that as a default value:

```
insert into Orders (Total) values (default);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c172006bca7d4304581cffb1500de40c) is a db<>fiddle.